# Rename model keeping same table name

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I realized I mistakenly pluralized my model name (`Requests` instead of `Request`).

The table was of course created as `Requests`, but for consistency I would like to rename my model to `Request` while keeping everything else the way it is now.

Running `add-migration` after renaming will create an empty migration, and yet running `update-database` says

> Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration.
>   You can use the Add-Migration command to write the pending model changes to a code-based migration.

Is there a quick way to do what I want?

Comment: i created a model Employees, changed it to Employee. added the initial migration, and then added another migration for namechange. it did create Up and Down methods with `RenameTable(name: "dbo.Employees", newName: "Employee");` in `Up()` and `RenameTable(name: "dbo.Employee", newName: "dbo.Employees");` in `Down()` methods

Comment: But that will rename the actual table, which I don't want to do: I only want to rename the *model*, because the table name already is what I want it to be.

Comment: oh, ill post an answer for that then

Comment: The pluralizing name convention is default, so if your class is singular and database table is plural you shouldn't need attributes or fluent (unless you want them). Seems like your issue is getting the database model in sync with the code model. Did add-migration create a migration in the folder?

Answer (score 2):

Create a Configuration class like so:

```
public class ChangedModelConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ChangedModelName>
    {
        public ChangedModelConfiguration()
        {
            ToTable("SameTableName", "YourSchemaName");
        }
    }
```

Then add in your DbContext's derived Class' `OnModelCreating` method

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ChangedModelConfiguration());
}
```

Or

Just add in your DbContext's derived Class' `OnModelCreating` method

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ChangedModelName>().ToTable("SameTableName", "YourSchemaName");
}
```

Or

if you like DataAnnotations better, Just add this attribute on top of your model like so:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

[Table("YourSchemaName.SameTableName")]
public partial class ChangedModelName
{
    // Model properties
}
```